# Storing and retrieving salt from a MySQL database

Tags: java, sql, salt

I have a PasswordEncryptionService, where I hash my passwords and save them in my MySQL database along with the salt used to hash them. I'm saving both my Passwords and my Salt as a byte array, and I have heard that I can just save them as the varbinary type in the SQL database.

Here is my code:

```
 //this method is used to retrieve the salt when a user is logging in 
 public static byte[] getSaltMethod(String username, String password) throws SQLException, LoginSampleException {

    try {

        Connection con = Connector.connection();

        String SQL = "SELECT * from Users.Salt WHERE email = ?, password = ?";

        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
        statement.setString(1, username);
        statement.setString(2, password);

        ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery();

        while (set.next()) {

            // vi skal ikke have en blolb her alligevel
            byte[] salt = set.getBytes("salt");
            //release the blob and free up memory. (since JDBC 4.0)
            /* jeg er i tivil om denne skal være her*/

            return salt;

        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Conf.MYLOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        throw new LoginSampleException(ex.getSQLState());
    }
    return null;

}



//this method is used to save the user along with the salt when a user is signing up

 public static void createUser(User user) throws LoginSampleException, NoSuchAlgorithmException 
{
    try {
        PasswordEncryptionService PE = new PasswordEncryptionService();
        byte[] salt = PE.generateSalt();
        Connection con = Connector.connection();
        String SQL = "INSERT INTO Users (email, password, phone, post, adress, role, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(SQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        ps.setString(1, user.getEmail());
        ps.setString(2, user.getPassword());
        ps.setString(3, user.getPhonenumber());
        ps.setString(4, user.getPostalCode());
        ps.setString(5, user.getAddress());
        ps.setString(6, user.getRole());
        ps.setBytes(7, salt);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ResultSet ids = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
        ids.next();
        int id = ids.getInt(1);
        user.setId(id);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new LoginSampleException(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Right now I have a separate method for retrieving the salt, and logging in the person, should I save the salt in a different table, or can it be saved in the user object? Should I save it as a varbinary or just a regular varchar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is homework then you can save them as varchar or binary. Whichever pleases you teacher is OK.

Now, for production, I have saved hashes as `binary` and as `varchar`, and I (personally) prefer binary. As binary, I have saved them both as a single (concatenated) column, or as two separate columns (salt & hash).

Benefits for `varchar`:

- It's easy to debug, to backup, to print, to compare in case you need it.
- It's easy to concatenate and to separate its parts. All string functions are available.
- Even the most green developer understands how to manage (concatenate, substring, etc.) strings.

Benefits/Disadvantages of `binary`:

- No need to encode back and forth between `String` and `byte[]`. Base64 or hexa encoding requires more coding, or the use of non-standard libraries.
- Many developers are not familiar with `[var]binary` or `blob` data type columns.
- Many SQL tools do not display binary columns well, something that makes it more difficult to bebug, or just to check it's doing the right thing.

Other than that, I prefer `[var]binary` since it's less java coding.

Comment: Is there any difference in the code, to rather I should use varbinary or varchar, or is the code the same??

Comment: Same code. When using varchar, you'll need to add the extra step of converting the hash from binary to a string (using Base 64 or plain hexa).